# Loop through odd numbered cells in a selected range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range selected in a single row and have a code which I want to loop through every odd cell in that range.
Let's say the range is of 20 cells. I want the loop to act on cell no. 1,3,5 and so on.
Which loop would be best and what's the syntax?

Comment: Look up the use of Step in a For loop

Answer (score 0):

Try This!

```
Sub SkipColumn()

Dim ColNum As Integer, RowNum As Integer

RowNum = 1

 For ColNum = 1 To 26 Step 2

    If Cells(RowNum, ColNum).Value = "" Then
    
        Cells(RowNum, ColNum).Value = "Hello"
        
    End If

 Next ColNum

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. However my question was different. The range is in a single row. For example the range could be A1:Z1. I want the loop to check the value entered in A1, C1, E1 and so on for a if then condition and auto populate some fields.

Comment: My mistake. I've revised the code to hopefully suit what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

### Using Step in a For...Next Loop

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub EveryOther()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("D1:Z1")
    ' Or:
    'Set rg = Selection
    'Set rg = Selection.Rows(1)
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    Debug.Print "ColumnIndex", "ColumnAddress"
    
    For c = 1 To rg.Columns.Count Step 2 ' every other cell
        ' Do your thing, e.g.:
        Debug.Print c, rg.Columns(c).Address(0, 0)
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

**Results in the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)**

```
ColumnIndex   ColumnAddress
 1            D1
 3            F1
 5            H1
 7            J1
 9            L1
 11           N1
 13           P1
 15           R1
 17           T1
 19           V1
 21           X1
 23           Z1
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this should do the trick. I'll try this tonight and let you know how it works.

Comment: This worked. I had to tweak my code a little to offset the active cell. But it worked and I could get the desired result. Thanks again.